# Identifying the pairs of ID's in a column with the highest number of matches in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the pairs of businesses with the highest number of common customers using MySQL.

The table is like the following:

```
+------------+------------+ 
| BusinessID | CustomerID |
+------------+------------+
| A          |          1 |
| A          |          2 |
| A          |          3 |
| B          |          4 |
| B          |          1 |
| B          |          3 |
| B          |          2 |
| C          |          3 |
| C          |          4 |
| C          |          5 |
+------------+------------+
```

And I want the output to be the pairs of businesses and the number of common customers, like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------------+
| BusinessID  | BusinessID  | Common Customers Count |
+-------------+-------------+------------------------+
| A           | B           |                      3 |
| A           | C           |                      1 |
| B           | C           |                      2 |
+-------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT a.BusinessID,b.BusinessID,COUNT(*) AS ncom
FROM (SELECT BusinessID, CustomerID FROM MYTABLE) AS a JOIN       
     (SELECT BusinessID,CustomerID FROM MYTABLE) AS b 
     ON a.BusinessID < b.BusinessID AND a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
GROUP BY a.BusinessID, b.BusinessID
ORDER BY ncom
```

The problem is that my dataset has about 5m rows, and this seems to be too inefficient on large datasets.  I tested the query on smaller datasets by limiting the data -- it took 8 seconds to process 10k rows and 30 seconds for 20k rows, so this query wouldn't be feasible to run for 5m rows. How else can I write the query to make it faster?

Comment: That's a strange requirement. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @bc004346 the requirement on speed? It would probably take several hours if not the entire day to run my query on the entire data set.  Just thought there had to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use subqueries to get the columns from the table, that's probably preventing it from using indexes.

```
SELECT a.BusinessID, b.BusinessID, COUNT(*) as ncom
FROM MYTABLE AS a
JOIN MYTABLE AS b ON a.BusinessID < b.BusinessID AND a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
GROUP BY a.BusinessID, b.BusinessID
ORDER BY ncom
```

Also, give the table the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_cust_bus ON MYTABLE (CustomerID, BusinessID);
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Didn't know subqueries would do that.

Comment: A subquery essentially creates a temporary table. But it doesn't have any indexes configured.